# Confused at how to structure my SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    `people`.`surename`, 
    calcWeight(`people`.`surname`,'kiera',6)
    as `weight`
FROM
    `people`
LEFT JOIN
    `dogs`
ON
    `people`.`id` = `dogs`.`owner` 
ORDER BY 
    `weight` DESC
```

The problem is i need to remove all results where `weight`, which is a value I'm calculating is 0. I thought it would be WHERE `weight` > 0 but apparently `weight` doesnt exist till after the where clause. I dont know if i am meant to move where `weight` is calculated or move the WHERE.

I dont want to do

```
 WHERE calcWeight(`people`.`surname`,'kiera',6) > 0
```

because calcWeight takes a long time to compute (when it's happening on thousands of rows) and i dont know if it would cache the result and re-use it.

Any help and advice would be great!
Thankyou !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right before your `ORDER BY` clause, add `HAVING weight > 0`.  `HAVING` clauses can reference aggregate functions and aliases you've set up in your `SELECT` clause.

The difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING` is that `WHERE` is executed before the result set is projected, and `HAVING` is executed on the actual projected result set.  Therefore, `WHERE` has more opportunities to use indexes (I don't think `HAVING` filters can use indexes at all), but `HAVING` is a bit more flexible.  Use `WHERE` when possible, and `HAVING` otherwise.

Comment: There are no aggregate functions in this query.  The `having` clause is entirely inappropriate.

Comment: In standard SQL, you are correct.  But MySQL extends `HAVING` to allow such expressions to reference `SELECT` aliases.  From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html): *"A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses."*

Comment: As a side note, it's good to see that people still do their research before downvoting...

Comment: The point was not about using expressions in the `having` clause.  The original query has no `group by`.  The `having` clause is inappropriate when there is no aggregation, in general.

Comment: In general, yes.  However, MySQL makes it useful to filter on an `SELECT` alias/computation.  In standard SQL, you either have to repeat the computation or use a subquery, as in your example.  MySQL provides a shortcut, if compatibility with other databases is not a concern.

Comment: Im putting this as the answer because although the little query i showed you didnt have aggregate functions, the full query does, i just cut it out to make it easier to read, (wont do that again). Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You best way to do this with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT `people`.`surename`, calcWeight(`people`.`surname`,'kiera',6) as `weight`
      FROM `people` LEFT JOIN
           `dogs`
           ON  `people`.`id` = `dogs`.`owner` 
     ) t
where weight > 0
ORDER BY `weight` DESC
```